# DropDownListFor binding to the text displayed not the underlying id (razor)

Tags: data-binding, razor, text, dropdownlistfor

I have a razor (cshtml) file with a dropdownlistfor:

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.x_nme, (SelectList) ViewData["Y"]);

The SelectList is formed in the controller as:

var = new SelectList(xList, "id", "x_nme", current.id);

ViewData["Y"] = y_var;

I want the model to bind to the "x_nme" attribute, which displays correctly in the dropdown, but instead it binds to the id attribute.

I need the id attribute as this dropdown fills several fields in the form using javascript/ajax/jquery and I could as an alternative bind to a hidden field to get the name correct.

I was wondering if there is a way to directly bind the model => model.x_nme to the text in the drop-down instead of the underlying id w/o having to have a hidden field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts?  I don't see any responses ....

Comment: Still no answer.  Not sure if this is intrinsically impossible at least for MVC 4, VS 2012, etc.  If anyone finds an answer please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: I made an answer below, if anyone has better syntax or other thoughts, please feel free to post an alternate answer or make a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewData["Y"] = new SelectList(xList, "Text", "Text");

Then there *is* only text on the dropdown, so it will be selected!

This actually works!

Comment: You won't get the ID of selected item. I think its a bad practice. Must there be a better way.

Comment: in this case, I was seeking text; however, if an ID is desired, you're absolutely correct, there would be a better way...